# Why there is a position argument in insert function of set in STL

Tags: c++, stl, set

Set always insert the element in sorted order, so there should be no use to tell the position to insert.

```
iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);
```

So why there is a position argument, is it useful?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument will be used as the hint of the insert positioin for [`std::set::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert), to improve the complexity if it points to the right position.

> hint  - iterator to the position before which the new element will be inserted    (since C++11)
>
> Complexity
>   Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position
>   just after the hint, logarithmic in the size of the container
>   otherwise.

One of the possible case is for modifying the element of `set` (suppose won't change the sort order). `std::set::iterator` is const iterator, it means you couldn't modify the element by a `std::set::iterator` directly. You could (1) locate the element, (2) make a copy and modify the copy, (3) remove the element from `set`, (4) insert the copy as new value. At the 4th step you can pass the iterator got at 3rd step to `std::set::insert` as the hint.

Answer (score 1):

It is used as a hint where new element should be inserted, also it makes `std::set` interface compatible with other containers ie. `std::vector:insert`, this way you can use [std::inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) which assums type has `T::insert` like operation.

You can also optimize inserts by first using [std::set::equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/equal_range), if both returned iterators are equal it means no element was found and iterators point to place where this element could be inserted:

```
std::set<int> s = {0,1,2,3,5,6,7};    
auto r = s.equal_range(4);
if ( r.first == r.second )
  s.insert(r.first, 4);
```